# Swiftmailer sends one message but not another

Tags: php, swiftmailer

My task is to create an online store. When the user has added goods to the basket and begins the process of placing an order, he/she and one of the managers will be sent an email about the order using Swiftmailer.

For some reason only the email to the manager arrives; the one to the user does not.

This is my code:

```
public static function mailOrder($order_id, $user_email){
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport(App::$app->getProperty('smtp_host'), App::$app->getProperty('smtp_port'), App::$app->getProperty('smtp_protocol')))
        ->setUsername(App::$app->getProperty('smtp_login'))
        ->setPassword(App::$app->getProperty('smtp_password'))
    ;
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
    ob_start();
    require APP . '/views/mail/mail_order_admin.php';
    require APP . '/views/mail/mail_order_user.php';
    $bodyAdmin = ob_get_clean();
    $bodyUser = ob_get_clean();
    $message_client = (new Swift_Message("Your order №{$order_id} on " . App::$app->getProperty('shop_name')))
        ->setFrom([App::$app->getProperty('smtp_login') => App::$app->getProperty('shop_name')])
        ->setTo($user_email)
        ->setBody($bodyUser, 'text/html')
    ;
    $message_admin = (new Swift_Message("Сделан заказ №{$order_id}"))
        ->setFrom([App::$app->getProperty('smtp_login') => App::$app->getProperty('shop_name')])
        ->setTo(App::$app->getProperty('admin_email'))
        ->setBody($bodyAdmin, 'text/html')
    ;
    $result = $mailer->send($message_client);
    $result = $mailer->send($message_admin);
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    unset($_SESSION['cart_qty']);
    unset($_SESSION['cart_sum']);
    unset($_SESSION['cart.currency']);
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Thank for Order';
}
```

Comment: You need to show what debugging effort you have made - for example what are the return values from the calls to `send`? Does Swiftmailer have a debug option to show more of what it is doing? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: [2019-09-25 17:30:59] Text of error: Address in mailbox given [admin_email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. | File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ishop2.loc/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php | Line: 355

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you posted, it would suggest that whatever is returned from `App::$app->getProperty('admin_email')` is not an email address – it may be returning the property name as the email address, which is no use to anyone. Check it with:

```
var_dump(App::$app->getProperty('admin_email'));
```

and then make sure you have the correct value in your config.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I found a solution to this problem
The thing about buffering was
Here's how the buffering options should have looked
'  // Create a message
        ob_start();
        $bodyAdmin = require APP . '/views/mail/mail_order_admin.php';
        $bodyAdmin =ob_get_clean();
        ob_start();
        $bodyUser = require APP . '/views/mail/mail_order_user.php';
        $bodyUser =ob_get_clean();'